# Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.remove(int)' on a null object reference | Trying to delete from recycler view

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to delete from a recycler view, but I am getting errors and don't know why. I am listening for delete button clicks and sending the id to the main activity to be deleted but it says the List is null and it should not be! I want to delete an item from recycler view when the button is clicked and it's linked to an id of the item which is sent to mainactivity to be deleted from productList but says it is null when it clearly loaded lots of elements on onCreate

---

This is the `MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mainToolBar;

    private AdView mAdView;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProductAdapter adapter;

    List<Product> productList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        loadData();



        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



        adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity_add.class));


        return true;
    }



    public void deleteItem(int id){

        id = id - 1;
        productList.remove(id);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(id);
    }
    private void loadData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared 
        prefs", 0);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("items", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Product>>(){}.getType();
        productList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        if(productList == null){
            productList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    private void addToList(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared prefs", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(productList);
        editor.putString("items", json);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

And this is the `ProductAdapter` class:

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder>{

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Product> productList;

    public ProductAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Product product = productList.get(position);

        holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
        holder.textViewRating.setText(String.valueOf(product.getRating()));



        holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new MainActivity().deleteItem(product.getId());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textViewTitle, textViewRating;

        Button deleteBtn;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            textViewRating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRating);

            deleteBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the variable `productList`?

Comment: in loadData() and at the top of MainActivity

Comment: Could you post that method?

Comment: ya just updated it, meant to add but accidentally left it out

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to create a new instance of `MainActivity` here:

`new MainActivity().deleteItem(product.getId());`

Your `MainActivity` should implement a listener and then you can pass it to `ProductAdapter` constructor:

`deleteListener.deleteItem(product.getId())`

Comment: i dont really understand what implementing a listener is and how to implement it

Comment: i just want to call a function in main activity that can update a list and then update the recycler view and save it into shared preferences